# How do I create a batch file that will search all subdirectories for filetypes and copy them to a folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is what I have:

for /R %i in (*.swf) do copy %i C:/testfolder/

I get the error "The system cannot find the file specified.

It's finding the .swf's just fine, but it's not copying them.

Comment: If you typed that as it appears here, you would probably get "The syntax of the command is incorrect." (I say "probably" because I tested on XP, and other versions of Windows might be different.). Using backslashes for the path (C:\testfolder\\) made it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to put the argument to `copy` in quotes as well as use backslashes:

```
for /R %i in (*.swf) do copy "%i" C:\testfolder\
```

(though I seriously wonder why you're playing around in the root directory of the drive).

And remember to double the `%` if you're using that in a batch file.

Comment: I'm on Windows XP, testing it from the command line first.  Not in the root, I'm actually running this from a path, but omitted the folder due to client privacy. 

I'm getting "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Answer (score 0):

Use [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx).

See [Example 1](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine133.htm) — it is relative to your problem.

Comment: While a nice suggestion this is overkill for something such simple. That's like all the folks who suggest installing cygwin for every minor problem in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [xcopy](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm) with the excludes argument (if you know what other types of files are present):

```
xcopy C:\sourcedir C:\destdir /EXCLUDE:excludes.txt /e
```

Where excludes.txt has a pattern of files not to copy on each line:

```
.svn
.obj
.js
```

Comment: This will copy the directory structure too, though. From what the OP attempted this isn't what s?he wants.

Comment: Yes this would not work as I do not need the directory structure or want to have to exclude other file types.

Simply search for all SWF files within a Folder/SubFolders and copy those to a separate folder.